# execute java class with ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I want my ant script to execute the command

java -cp libs/a.jar:libs/b.jar org.stack.class1 --package pName --out classes new.wsdl

How can I do it with an Ant script? The following does not work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="class" default="compile">
<target name="compile">
    <java classname="org.stack.class1" fork="true">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="libs/a.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="libs/b.jar"/>

    </classpath>
    <arg value="--package pName --out classes new.wsdl"/>

    </java>
</target>
```

It complains that --package pName --out classes new.wsdl is an argument for java. However I want --package pName --out classes new.wsdl to be arguments to org.stack.class1

Comment: how it doesn't work? exception? doesn't generate class? warning?

Comment: You are on the right track. Perhaps you are missing a < in front of project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with your arg value. According to the documentation [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg), you are not specifying two separate command line arguments with

```
<arg value="--package pName --out classes new.wsdl"/>
```

I would try changing it to

```
<arg line="--package pName --out classes new.wsdl"/>
```

Comment: That has gotten me in the past as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the `java` task, the `<arg>` elements take a single token each.  Try something like this

```
<arg value="--package"/>
<arg value="pName"/>
<arg value="--out"/>
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

The value parameter of the arg tag can only take one parameter. See the [documentation of the arg tag.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg)

Try adding several arg tags, one for each parameter.